# Which is the most powerful fan less iMac that uses a CRT for the display?

Tags: imac

I am planning to use it as jukebox but I just know that apple started selling fanless iMac from 350mhz model...
When did they stop doing fanless imacs?
700 mhz?

I just care about crt models.

Comment: There are also fanless iCubes up to 500MHz

Comment: That's right but since I have  to build the greatest jukebox ever I need an iMac: superior sound quality :)

Comment: What is the difference in the sound cards - also for best surely you should use an external USB->analog DAC

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear...
I mean the best integrated sound system (imac had harman kardon and were fanless: really surprising quality)

Comment: Wikipedia is a great place to see the CPU on these macs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Macintosh_models_grouped_by_CPU_type - what exactly is most powerful? Loudest speakers? CPU? GPU? hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to beat a fanless iPod and a set of fanless speakers for the power of great sound. I'm in love with my [iPod HiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Hi-Fi) and a Belkin Bluetooth receiver for when I don't want connect my iPod through headphone or dock connector.

It won't satisfy your CRT interest, but I suppose no answer can be perfect... ;-)

Comment: ... and yes, this is a snarky, but hopefully humorous non-answer.

Comment: And it doesn't care at all about how good that babe'll look in my room U_U
And has no heart for antiques :D

Comment: I want a Banana Jr playing some vintage james brown or meters for nostalgia's sake, but the color G3 bubble iMac have the best sounding speakers that EVER shipped with a mac - even the 20th anniversary + sub woofer to my ears.

Comment: I do - obviously - agree